# How to set property in static variable in function

Tags: swift, swift2

In this case the static variable textView is contained in Holder struct.
But I encountered a problem that I have to set "Holder.textView.fieldEditor = true" every time when user invoke this function.
How do I let this action only run once?

```
func myTextView() -> NSTextView {

    struct Holder {
        static var textView = NSTextView()
    }

    Holder.textView.fieldEditor = true
    return Holder.textView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
struct Holder {
    static var textView = NSTextView()
}
```

should be defined outside the scope of your function. Otherwise each time you call `myTextView()` a new `Holder` struct is defined and instantiated.

This makes the `static var` useless for your purpose.

On the other hand, if you define `Holder` outside the function the value does persist among multiple calls.

Look

[image]